# uTorrent Classic to uTorrent Web migration

Tags: migration, torrent

How can I migrate user data from uTorrent Classic to uTorrent Web?

---

Ideally, I would like to keep both list of torrents and download state.

It *looks like* `resume.dat` can be migrated--though I can't find whether the format is the same.

It's unclear:

- where to place all the `.torrent` files to be properly picked up by uT Web.
- whether those torrents originally added to uT Classic as magnet links will be picked up by uT Web
- is there anything else I can/should consider migrating--and how

---

RESEARCH DONE:

There is nothing relevant on the topic:

- migration overall: [this is the closest](https://help.bittorrent.com/en/support/solutions/articles/29000039597-how-do-i-migrate-torrents-from-a-different-client-to-bittorrent-) I've got from the uTorrent team, and it's about reverse migration from uT Web to uT Classic
- [similar question](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/113405-resume-downloads-on-web-version-from-client-version/) on user support forum is replied by other user "you can try ... and see what happens"; no official representative ever joined the conversation. *-- I tried, with and without copying `.torrent` files to `~/Library/Application Support/uTorrent Web`: always result in empty list of downloads*
- .torrents location: two questions on user support forum, both unanswered: [1](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/111055-where-are-torrent-files-stored/), [2](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/109548-where-are-torrent-stored/)

Comment: Doesn’t uTorrent have a support site? Also, assuming you asked there and didn’t get a reply, please focus your question on one specific problem.

Comment: _> please focus your question on one specific problem_: It's that simple: "How can I migrate user data from uTorrent Classic to uTorrent Web?"

Comment: Well, if even on the support site the best answer is "you can try ... and see what happens": did you try? Don't think you'll get a better answer here.